# Why does my cube in three.js have aliasing and look "Jaggy"?

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, rendering

I am using three.js and created a basic scene with a few meshses rendered with some basic lighting . My torus geometry was previously pointy with few polygons but I was able to smooth it out by adding more segments but now I would like to straighten the lines out in my cube. They seem jaggy. In the pic I am including my render on the left seems a lot jaggier then the example I am following on the right. I have even set width and height segments to very large values (200). Any Ideas why the aliasing/jagginess?[My render on left, example on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkCl3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need to share your code. Specifically, please at least share the parts where you create/initialize your renderer, and where you actually render your scene.

Comment: Have you set the antialiasing to true in the renderer? By default it is turned off.

Comment: No , I will give this a try thankyou.